# Comma usage/ introductory element

Tags: word-usage, british-english

Concerning this question: what would be the the usage of a comma in either of the last two examples. (a comma version and a comma less version).

After 'You can virtually guarantee to get a good tan in June in the Caribbean or on the Mediterranean.' I'd want the comma'd version. [But I haven't checked the weather facts.]

After 'I like to visit Palm Springs/ to be sure rain won't interfere with my golf practice.' I might well use the comma-less version.

I can see a potential comma after Palm Springs but not on the other sentence.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/322373/is-a-comma-necessary-after-an-introductory-but-a-main-clause-dependent-element

Comment: I don't see introductory clauses in these examples. You should point them out in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anywhere a comma would fit in either of your sentences as they are currently. The SE question you linked is about using commas after introductory clauses, which neither of your questions have.

An example of a sentence with an introductory clause would be:

> In Palm Springs, I can be sure the rain wont interfere with my golf practice.

The introductory clause here is *in Palm Springs* and the main clause is *I can be sure the rain wont interfere with my gold practice*.

**However**, these commas are entirely optional and if you can avoid them  you should. Personally, in the above sentence I wouldn't use a comma.

Also, there are a few errors in your first sentence, and fixing one of them results in an introductory clause:

> **In June, you are** virtually guarantee**d** to get a good tan in the Caribbean or the Mediterranean **region**.

Firstly, [adverb order](https://owl.excelsior.edu/grammar-essentials/parts-of-speech/adverbs/order-of-adverbs/) makes the *in June in the Caribbean* sound awkward. Normally, we'd just rearrange the adverbs but in this case you need them in this particular order for the sentence to make sense. So, we make the *in June* part an introductory clause. I put the comma in because it further removes *in June* from the other adverbs (making the fact that we are ignoring adverb order less obvious).

Secondly, *you can virtually guarantee to* is a common mistake. The grammatical version is *you are virtually guaranteed to*.

Finally, *the Mediterranean* can't be used like *the Caribbean*. *The Caribbean* is a name on its own, but *the Mediterranean* isn't (unless you're talking about a hotel called 'The Mediterranean' or something). Instead I used *the Mediterranean region*, but *area* or some other noun works fine.